# While & for loop saving all results

Tags: r, loops

Hey guys I have a problem with while and for loops, more precisely I need to figure out how to properly save the results without being overwritten by the last one, so its a more general question, but I haven't found any solution to this yet on any site.

The analysis in the middle part is not important, since its working. The only problem is that the results are overwritten after each Enterprise and i couldn't figure out how to save a list with all of them in it. I am analysing text where the output should be: 
positive_rating; negative_rating; positive_words; negative_words; word_count; Files;firm for each quartal

For now the result is a list of all the quartals of "Adecco Grou AG"

I can't provide examples but the texts and dictionaries consist of single column matrices with one word of the text in each row.

I hope i could express myself enough clearly and thanks in advance for the help!

```
library(readxl)
library(readr)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)

path = "C:/Users/benja/OneDrive/Studium/Bachelorarbeit/Ressourcen/Conference Calls/Text_formated/"


#Import Dictionary
positive_list <- read_excel("C:/Users/benja/OneDrive/Studium/Bachelorarbeit/Ressourcen/LoughranMcDonald_MasterDictionary_2014.xlsx", 
                            sheet = "positive")
negative_list <- read_excel("C:/Users/benja/OneDrive/Studium/Bachelorarbeit/Ressourcen/LoughranMcDonald_MasterDictionary_2014.xlsx", 
                            sheet = "negative")
#Initiate result list
positive_rating <- list()
negative_rating <- list()
word_count <- list()
positive_words <- list()
negative_words <- list()

Files <- c(  "2011 Q1.csv","2011 Q2.csv","2011 Q3.csv","2011 Q4.csv",
             "2012 Q1.csv","2012 Q2.csv","2012 Q3.csv","2012 Q4.csv",
             "2013 Q1.csv","2013 Q2.csv","2013 Q3.csv","2013 Q4.csv",
             "2014 Q1.csv","2014 Q2.csv","2014 Q3.csv","2014 Q4.csv",
             "2015 Q1.csv","2015 Q2.csv","2015 Q3.csv","2015 Q4.csv",
             "2016 Q1.csv","2016 Q2.csv","2016 Q3.csv","2016 Q4.csv")
Enterprise <- c("ABB Ltd","Actelion Ltd", "Adecco Group AG")
g1 <- length(Enterprise)
company <- as.integer(1)

while(company <= g1){
  for (i in 1:length(Files))
  { 
    ##**ANALYSIS**##

  firm <- Enterprise[company]

  }
company <- company+1
}

#Add Identifier to list
Rating_list =cbind(positive_rating,negative_rating,positive_words,negative_words,word_count,Files, firm)

View(Rating_list)
```

Just in case I leave the whole code in the end, if its needed.

```
library(readxl)
library(readr)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)

path = "C:/Users/benja/OneDrive/Studium/Bachelorarbeit/Ressourcen/Conference Calls/Text_formated/"


#Import Dictionary
positive_list <- read_excel("C:/Users/benja/OneDrive/Studium/Bachelorarbeit/Ressourcen/LoughranMcDonald_MasterDictionary_2014.xlsx", 
                            sheet = "positive")
negative_list <- read_excel("C:/Users/benja/OneDrive/Studium/Bachelorarbeit/Ressourcen/LoughranMcDonald_MasterDictionary_2014.xlsx", 
                            sheet = "negative")
#Initiate result list
positive_rating <- list()
negative_rating <- list()
word_count <- list()
positive_words <- list()
negative_words <- list()

Files <- c(  "2011 Q1.csv","2011 Q2.csv","2011 Q3.csv","2011 Q4.csv",
             "2012 Q1.csv","2012 Q2.csv","2012 Q3.csv","2012 Q4.csv",
             "2013 Q1.csv","2013 Q2.csv","2013 Q3.csv","2013 Q4.csv",
             "2014 Q1.csv","2014 Q2.csv","2014 Q3.csv","2014 Q4.csv",
             "2015 Q1.csv","2015 Q2.csv","2015 Q3.csv","2015 Q4.csv",
             "2016 Q1.csv","2016 Q2.csv","2016 Q3.csv","2016 Q4.csv")
Enterprise <- c("ABB Ltd","Actelion Ltd", "Adecco Group AG")
g1 <- length(Enterprise)
company <- as.integer(1)

while(company <= g1){
  for (i in 1:length(Files))
  { 
    #Import Text
    Text <- read_delim(paste0(path,Enterprise[company],"/",Files[i]), 
                       ";", escape_double = FALSE, col_names = FALSE, 
                       trim_ws = TRUE)
    #Formating ->  Transp, Vector, small, dataframe
    Text = data.frame(tolower(c(t(Text))))
    colnames(Text) = "Word"
    #Joining Text-Dictionary
    positive_rate = inner_join(positive_list,Text)
    #Analysis
    positive_rate$count <- 1
    positive_rating[[i]] = sum(positive_rate$Rating) 
    positive_words[[i]] = sum(positive_rate$count)

    #Import Text
    Text <- read_delim(paste0(path,Enterprise[company],"/",Files[i]), 
                       ";", escape_double = FALSE, col_names = FALSE, 
                       trim_ws = TRUE)
    #Formating ->  Transp, Vector, small, dataframe
    Text = data.frame(tolower(c(t(Text))))
    colnames(Text) = "Word"
    #negative part
    negative_rate = inner_join(negative_list,Text)
    #Analysis
    negative_rate$count <- 1
    negative_rating[[i]] = sum(negative_rate$Rating)
    negative_words[[i]] = sum(negative_rate$count)

    #Import Text
    Text <- read_delim(paste0(path,Enterprise[company],"/",Files[i]), 
                       ";", escape_double = FALSE, col_names = FALSE, 
                       trim_ws = TRUE)
    #Formating ->  Transp, Vector, small, dataframe
    Text = data.frame(tolower(c(t(Text))))
    colnames(Text) = "Word"
    #Word counting 
    Text <- na.omit(Text)
    Text$count <- 1
    word_count[[i]] = sum(Text$count)

  firm <- Enterprise[company]

  }
company <- company+1
}

#Add Identifier to list
Rating_list =cbind(positive_rating,negative_rating,positive_words,negative_words,word_count,Files, firm)


View(Rating_list)
```

Comment: try incorporating a counter variable at one at the beginning of the loop, add one each time you cycle through the loop. Then build an assign function which pastes the name to that counter number.

Comment: Do you mean like I did for company <- company +1 ?

Comment: Yes, `loopData<-paste(firm, "_", company)` and if you want to keep the variable to use outside the loop you can use that identifier to assign it to a global variable `assign("newVariable" , loopData,envir = .GlobalEnv)` that should giva  variable named `firm_1` then `firm_2`...is that what you want?

Comment: Use `for (firm in Enterprise) ` `for (file in Files) `, these `while` and `i` are unnecessary.  Then your problem may be solved by `word_count[[length(word_count+1)]] <- sum(Text$count)`

Comment: I am sorry but since I do no use R so often I cannot follow your explanation.

@Moody_Mudskipper the loop itself is not the problem. I just can't figure out how i can save all the output of the different quartals and comapnies in one list